# How to pass a variable as the text in <a href></a> of asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have this code in aspx page which is working:

```
 <a href="javascript:openPopup('/subsidy /updatehour1.aspx?ProjectID=<%# Eval("Data1") %>')" > 7 </a>
```

I can not find a way to replace the text `7` with `'<%# Bind("Data2") %>`'. Any idea how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Post more code to make question clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='javascript:openPopup('/subsidy /updatehour1.aspx?ProjectID=<%# Eval("Data1") %>'><%# Eval("Data1")%></a>
```

Comment: I just tried the second solution and it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome :) If it works then just upvote, so that other who are facing same problem will help them. :)